# Is there such a thing as a Per-User Global Assembly Cache?

Tags: .net, caching, gac

Question says it all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The global assembly cache is a repository for assemblies installed on the given machine, that is, its machine based, not user based.

Answer (score 1):

No, the GAC is global to machine as the name suggests. However, you can simulate one. Just stick the assemblies in a folder structure similar to the GAC's and then write your own assembly resolution code (see `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`). It's not quite the same as the real GAC (around security in particular) but it might suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can always copy assemblies into the local directory that your program runs in.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same, but note that ClickOnce installs are generally per-user - more comparable to `Program Files` than the GAC, though.

Comment: Fair point. If the application were small enough it could be copied int the users profile directory